# How can a powernap boost memeroy and cheerfulness?

Tags: brain, sleep

**Background**

> A power nap is a short sleep which terminates before the occurrence of
>   deep sleep or slow-wave sleep (SWS), intended to quickly revitalize
>   the subject. ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_nap))

The results of powernapping are described in [An ultra short episode of sleep is sufficient to promote declarative memory performance](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18275549)

> In the first experiment we assessed free recall of a list of 30 words
>   after a 60 min retention interval that was either filled with daytime
>   napping or waking activity. Memory performance was significantly
>   enhanced after napping as opposed to waking but was not correlated
>   with time spent in slow wave sleep or total sleep time within the
>   napping condition. The second experiment was designed to clarify the
>   role of total sleep time and therefore included an additional third
>   group, which was allowed to nap for no longer than 6 min on average.
>   In comparing word recall after conditions of no napping (waking),
>   short napping, and long napping, we found superior recall for both nap
>   conditions in contrast to waking as well as for long naps in contrast
>   to short naps. **These results demonstrate that even an ultra short
>   period of sleep is sufficient to enhance memory processing**

**Question**
I'm wondering **how** it's possible that such a short napping period can boost cheerfulness and memory (thus in a biological sense).

Comment: Perhaps better asked on CogSci?